# Reporting services in Sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

i know crystal reports very well and i work on this for last 3 years. 
I wanted to learn Reporting services of sqlserver so which is the best resource to learn the
Reporting services quickly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this one to learn reporting services :
http://www.apress.com/book/view/1590599926

A good book to learn and practice.

Answer (score 1):

I did learn almost all by practice, of course you should read a book or something like that, but the best way is to "play" with SSRS, don't forget to install the AdventureWorks sample database  since almost all the official SSRS examples uses this database, the examples will teach you what you can do with the software. 
Also you can try to "convert" some big reports from CR to SSRS in order to learn differences between each platform (i did it that way). With 3 year of CR experience this way into SSRS it will be a piece of cake :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the quickest way to get going and get your hands dirty is by taking a 1-2 day training course. This way you get to really play with the tools while you're there and can ask the instructor all your questions too. This usually buys you the instructor's email address for future questions. 1-2 days is really all you need to start out, then it's just playing with the tools from there on out and using Google or getting a book for the deeper topics.

I found a local course to take for ~$200 and I'll tell you, I asked a few million dollar questions that would have put me at a dead-end for a few days otherwise.

Comment: i need some resource which is online not for training base.
thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

you can learn watching tutorial video from https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/intro-ssrs-reporting ,after that you will be check https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/intro-ssrs-basic-2